# Problema ao tentar consumir o webservice no android

Tags: android, web-service, soap

estou tentando fazer um consultar atraves do android em um banco de dados firebird, o webservice esta funcionando perfeitamente porém ao tentar fazer a consulta atraves do aplicativo ele gera o seguinte erro:

```
05-31 13:55:52.339 4062-4062/br.com.realsysten.restaurante E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: br.com.realsysten.restaurante, PID: 4062                                                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.realsysten.restaurante/br.com.realsysten.restaurante.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.ArrayList.toString()' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.util.ArrayList.toString()' on a null object reference
 at br.com.realsysten.restaurante.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

eu tenho as seguintes classes:

Mesa:

```
package br.com.realsysten.restaurante;

import java.sql.Date;

/**
 * Created by Vitor on 31/05/2016.
 */
public class Mesa {

    private int id;
    private String barras;
    private String tipo;
    private Date data;
    private int lugares;
    private String situacao;
    private String descricao;
    private double credito;

    public Mesa(){
    }

    public Mesa(int id, String barras, String tipo, Date data, int lugares, String situacao, String descricao,
                double credito) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.barras = barras;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.data = data;
        this.lugares = lugares;
        this.situacao = situacao;
        this.descricao = descricao;
        this.credito = credito;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBarras() {
        return barras;
    }

    public void setBarras(String barras) {
        this.barras = barras;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public Date getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Date data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int getLugares() {
        return lugares;
    }

    public void setLugares(int lugares) {
        this.lugares = lugares;
    }

    public String getSituacao() {
        return situacao;
    }

    public void setSituacao(String situacao) {
        this.situacao = situacao;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public double getCredito() {
        return credito;
    }

    public void setCredito(double credito) {
        this.credito = credito;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Mesa{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", barras='" + barras + '\'' +
                ", tipo='" + tipo + '\'' +
                ", data=" + data +
                ", lugares=" + lugares +
                ", situacao='" + situacao + '\'' +
                ", descricao='" + descricao + '\'' +
                ", credito=" + credito +
                '}';
    }
}
```

MesaDAO:

```
package br.com.realsysten.restaurante;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Vector;

/**
 * Created by Vitor on 31/05/2016.
 */
public class MesaDAO {

    private static final String URL = "http://192.168.2.236:8080/SigadmWS/services/MesaDAO?wsdl";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://SigadmWS.realsysten.com.br";

    private static final String BUSCAR_TODOS = "buscarTodos";

    public ArrayList<Mesa> buscarTodos(){
        ArrayList<Mesa> lista = new ArrayList<Mesa>();

        SoapObject buscarMesa = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, BUSCAR_TODOS);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarMesa);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;

        HttpTransportSE htpp = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            htpp.call("urn:" + BUSCAR_TODOS, envelope);
            Vector<SoapObject> resposta = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope.getResponse();
            for(SoapObject soapObject : resposta){
                Mesa mesa = new Mesa();
                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

                mesa.setId(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("CON_CODIGO").toString()));
                mesa.setBarras(soapObject.getProperty("CON_CODIGO_BARRAS").toString());
                mesa.setTipo(soapObject.getProperty("CON_TIPO").toString());
                mesa.setData((java.sql.Date) format.parse(soapObject.getProperty("CON_DATA").toString()));
                mesa.setLugares(Integer.parseInt(soapObject.getProperty("CON_QTDE_LUGARES").toString()));
                mesa.setSituacao(soapObject.getProperty("CON_SITUACAO").toString());
                mesa.setDescricao(soapObject.getProperty("CON_DESCRICAO").toString());
                mesa.setCredito(Double.parseDouble(soapObject.getProperty("CON_VLR_CREDITO").toString()));

                lista.add(mesa);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        return lista;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package br.com.realsysten.restaurante;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        MesaDAO dao = new MesaDAO();

        ArrayList<Mesa> lista = dao.buscarTodos();
        Log.d("SigadmWS", lista.toString());
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.realsysten.restaurante">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ao rodar o debug, o erro ocorre na seguinte linha:

```
htpp.call("urn:" + BUSCAR_TODOS, envelope);
```

alguém sabe o porque?

obrigado desde ja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prezado, o erro está na requisição por algum motivo. Depois de alguns anos trabalhando com KSoap, criei uma certa estrutura e desejo ensiná-lo como resolver esse problema de maneira organizada com um código enxuto e sem acoplamentos de controle.

Seria muito importante você não misturar o tratamento de resultados da requisição com a chamada do serviço como você está fazendo em seus testes, para isto vou te enviar alguns fragmentos de código para te auxiliar na organização do seu código.

Além disso, é altamente não recomendável rodar strict mode, a não ser que sejam testes. Mas implemente as AsyncTasks corretamente ok.

Considere criar uma classe, por exemplo, Send.java com a implementação do Método call:

```
/**
     * Método que chama uma operação webservices
     * 
     * @param properties
     *            - Propriedades (Parâmetros de entrada)
     * @param namespace
     *            - namespace
     * @param methodName
     *            - método
     * @param url
     *            - url
     * @param action
     *            - action
     * @return InputStream.
     */
    public InputStream call(String url, String namespace, String methodName, String action, ArrayList<PropertyInfo> properties) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
        InputStream resultado;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);

        if (properties != null) {
            // Adicionando dinamicamente as propriedades.
            for (PropertyInfo property : properties) {
                request.addProperty(property);
            }
        }

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = false;

        MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
        md.register(envp);

        envp.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        try {
            //Adicionando um timeout de 2 minutos.
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url, 60000);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

            // System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            androidHttpTransport.call(action, envp);

            Object response = envp.getResponse();
            resultado = new ByteArrayInputStream(response.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
            Log.i("Send", "RESULTADO: " + resultado);

        } catch (IOException | XmlPullParserException e) {
            Log.e("Send", e.toString());
            throw e;
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Em seguida, crie separadamente as classes para trabalhar com cada um dos seus WebMethods (pode agrupar os métodos por afinidade - assunto). Aqui tenho um exemplo chamado WSInformacoesX (renomeei do real) que chama justamente o método desejado pela constante na chamada do método call da classe Send.

```
public class WSInformacoesX {

    private Send wsSender;
    private PropertyInfo pCODIGOUSUARIO;

    public WSInformacoesX() {
        wsSender = new Send();
    }

    public InputStream getInformacoesX(String codigousuario) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        ArrayList<PropertyInfo> propriedades = new ArrayList<>();

        pCODIGOUSUARIO = new PropertyInfo();
        pCODIGOUSUARIO.setName("CODIGOUSUARIO");
        pCODIGOUSUARIO.setValue(codigousuario);
        pCODIGOUSUARIO.setType(String.class);
        propriedades.add(pCODIGOUSUARIO);

        return wsSender.call(WSConfig.SOAP_URL, WSConfig.SOAP_NAMESPACE, WSConfig.SOAP_METHOD_GETINFORMACOESX, WSConfig.SOAP_ACTION_GETINFORMACOESX, propriedades);
    }
}
```

Além disso, é importante ressaltar que para cada resultado você pode ter um parser específico claro e bem organizado, realizando o parsing corretamente para cada tipo de objeto POJO que você possui, analisando o XML, por exemplo:

```
public class ParserResultadoOperacao {

    private ResultadoOperacao resultado;
    private String text;

    public ResultadoOperacao parse(InputStream is) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory;
        XmlPullParser parser;

        factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        parser = factory.newPullParser();

        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("app")) {
                    resultado = new ResultadoOperacao();
                }
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                text = parser.getText();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("status")) {
                    resultado.setStatus(Long.parseLong(text));
                } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("mensagem")) {
                    if (text != null) {
                        resultado.setMensagem(text);
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Claro, procure sempre ajustar seus parsers de formar que não escreva desnecessariamente código.

Para finalizar, o erro pode ser porque o método não está sendo encontrado. Defina uma classe por exemplo chamada WSConfig em que você coloque todos os métodos (e é usada acima na classe de chamada específica), por exemplo:

```
public static String SOAP_URL = "http://www.xpto.com/Services.php";

public static String SOAP_ACTION_GETINFORMACOESX = "urn:server#getInformacoesX";
public static String SOAP_METHOD_GETINFORMACOESX = "getInformacoesX";
```

Espero ter ajudado e bons códigos!